# Error compile application uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: java, android, gradle

When I compile the application it shows Error that 
the application uses or overrides a deprecated API

```
mEmailView =  findViewById(R.id.login_email);

      mPasswordView =  findViewById(R.id.login_password);
        googleButton = findViewById(R.id.google_button);

        mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == R.integer.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    attemptLogin();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        String text = "<font color=#cc0029>S</font><font color=#37BAF5>U</font><font color=#E000EE>M</font><font color=#BF0731>O</font>";
        textView3.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
        textView3.setScaleX(2.5f);

        // instance of FirebaseAuth



    }


        public void signInExistingUser(View v) {
        //  Call attemptLogin() here
    attemptLogin();

    }



    public void registerNewUser(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.one4all.sumotwo.RegisterActivity.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    private void attemptLogin() {
        String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();
        if (email.equals("") || password.equals("")) {
            return;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login progress...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        //FirebaseAuth to sign in with email and password
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    showError("Problem in sign in");
                } else {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, BottomNavigation.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

**Error**

tried to access method 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.io.Files.fileTreeTraverser()Lcom/google/common/collect/TreeTraverser; from class com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunVerifierTransform
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunVerifierTransform.processFolderInputs(InstantRunVerifierTransform.java:165)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunVerifierTransform.doTransform(InstantRunVerifierTransform.java:139)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunVerifierTransform.transform(InstantRunVerifierTransform.java:120)

Comment: Did you recently update Android Studio?

Comment: i will try @stkent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating the android studio it works.Here's the link https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html